# How to give a selectmenu a tooltip in jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm replacing a `select` with the new [jquery-ui selectmenu widget](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) (well: 'covering' would be more precise).

On the select I could easily add a tooltip. I am using [jquery-ui tooltip plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

I've tried but haven't managed to give the `selectmenu` one:

*** The tooltip on the select does not work any more
* Setting a tooltip to the top span of the selectmenu element (`'.ui-selectmenu-button'`) didn't work either**

Can it be done?

I'm using `jquery ui 1.11.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Lv57G/)** of jquery ui tooltip on jquery-ui selectmenu.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
     var select_id = "SelectMenu";
     $( "#"+select_id ).selectmenu();

     $( "#"+select_id+"-button").tooltip({items: "span", content: 'This is select'});
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="SelectMenu">Selectmenu example:</label>
    <select name="SelectMenu" id="SelectMenu">
        <option id="option1" title="Tooltip1">option1</option>
        <option id="option2" title="Tooltip2">option2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Two things I don't understand though: 1. Were do you have the '$( "#"+select_id+"-button")' magic from? 2. What does the 'items: "span"' part do? Without this it doesn't seem to work

Comment: o.k., '$( "#"+select_id+"-button")' turns up when I inspect the html that was created by jquery-ui

Comment: have you noticed that the tooltip for the select menu item (this is a select) hangs around longer than it should (at least in Chrome on windows) if you go quickly to the other items in the list?Seems it doesn't then get a lost focus message and the tooltip keeps showing